# Does the power supply matter?

Tags: mining-setup

I have a Gridseed 5-chip ASIC miner and am running 2 amps into it. Will this impact how it works and if it works at all if I use 2 amps instead of 5?

Comment: We'll need the voltage, actual amperage (5A?) and any other hardware detail to help. But if it's a case of running 2A through instead of 5A (60% reduction in amps) then the power will be reduced by 60% too, implying that the unit won't work (because if the miners could mine the same rate at less power it'd be done)

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie this isn't always true.  Many times, electronics will have a power supply with a greater amperage rating to handle spikes, etc.  So for example, if a circuit only needed 2 amps with maybe a little more for spikes, it might ship with a 5 amp PSU.  However, reducing it to 4 amps would still be within tolerance. I'm not saying the OT would be OK dropping down 60%, I'm just saying that it really depends on what the circuit actually needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a 12V 2A supply will be OK in scrypt only mode. I am using a 12V 1A for a gridseed in scrypt only mode. If you remove the fan @850Hz you can get the power usage down to 6W, other wise it is 8W. 12V x 2A gives maximum of 24W power available so loads of overhead.

CCTV 12V DC power splits are available for a few $/£ which can power multiple gridseeds if you have a 12V 5A supply. I am powering 4 from a 12V 5A supply with fans removed.

Comment: What if you're using a 12 V with 6 AMP? My pool isn't showing even 50% of what cgminer is on my side?

Comment: You could have a 12V with 100 AMPS.  That doesn't mean you are sending more power to the device.  It just means that it can handle 100 AMPS (or 6).  The circuit is only going to pull the power it needs unless you have something really strange going on.  Also, this is assuming we're talking about a regulated power supply.  Unregulated power supplies will alter the voltage as the amperage changes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you use a 12V/2A power supply rather than a 12V/5A supply, the voltage will drop, causing hardware errors. You will effectively be undervolting the chips.